# Как отправлять даныые типа "asset", я использую discord.ext.ipc, dicsord py

Tags: discord.py, quartz

Сайт на quart должен принимать "asset" данные с ipc бота, в котором прописано:

```
...

@bot.ipc.route()
async def get_members(data):
    guild = bot.get_guild(data.guild_id)

    members = []

    for user in guild.members:
        user_data = dict(name=user.name, id=user.id, avatar_url=user.avatar_url)
        members.append(user_data)
    return members
```

Но при попытке открыть сайт - я получаю ошибку:
`discord.ext.ipc.errors.JSONEncodeError: IPC route returned values which are not able to be sent over sockets. If you are trying to send a discord.py object, please only send the data you need.`

### Помогите пожалуйста исправить это

Возможно ли вообще отправлять данные asset?

Comment: Здраствуйте, а вы уже решили проблему. Только что с ней встретился

Comment: Нет, так и не вышло

Comment: Хотя с другой стороны, в проблеме чётко указано, что не нужно отправлять целый объект, постарайтесь извлечь нужные из объекта данные и отправить их либо по отдельности либо словарём, либо любимым json'ом